# Parse an integer value from string and check if it is greater or less than a given integer

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, sed

I have the following AWS CLI command which does a count of size of all buckets:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://my-bucket/2012/
```

and when I run this, this prints to console dozens of lines such as (small snippet taken):

```
2019-10-13 14:59:33    6.4 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:00:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:14    8.3 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:01:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:06    4.7 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:02:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:14    4.3 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:03:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 14:59:33    4.3 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:04:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:11    4.0 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:05:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:11    3.9 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:06:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 14:59:43    3.8 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:07:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 14:59:56    3.6 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:08:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:14    3.8 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:09:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:14    4.0 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:10:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:17    4.1 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:11:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:17    3.9 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:12:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:17    3.8 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:13:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:22    2.9 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:14:00Z.txt.gz
2019-10-13 15:00:37    4.3 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:15:00Z.txt.gz

Total Objects: 300
   Total Size: 1.7 GiB
```

I'm trying to see if I can have a Bash/Shell script that will parse out the size of each bucket e.g. **6.4** MiB, **8.3** Mib, **4.7** MiB etc... and check against a minimum threshold. If any of these buckets are under 3.0 MiB, it will print the name of that bucket and tell me, otherwise it'll carry on.

In this example, only one of them is under 3.0 MiB so it will print:

> 2019-10-13 15:00:22    2.9 MiB 2012/11/01/00/2012-11-01T00:14:00Z.txt.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a potential solution that converts the size into bytes based on an array that maps the unit name (e.g. MiB) to the number of bytes.

**EDIT:** Once the text "Total Objects:" appears at the beginning of a line, the program will exit.  Also, any lines that have fewer than 5 fields will be silently ignored.

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://my-bucket/2012/ | \
awk -v threshold_in_bytes=$((3*1024*1024)) '
  BEGIN {
    units["TiB"]=1024*1024*1024*1024
    units["GiB"]=1024*1024*1024
    units["MiB"]=1024*1024
    units["KiB"]=1024
    units["B"]=1
  }

  /^Total Objects:/ {
    exit
  }

  NF >= 5 {
    if ($4 in units) {
      if ($3 * units[$4] < threshold_in_bytes) {
        print $0    
      }
    }
    else {
      print "Error: Unknown unit on line " NR ": " $0
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: Looks great so far, I'm just getting an error: "Error: Unknown unit on line 302: Total Objects: 300. I used the following: ( | head -n -2 | awk NF | ) but not sure if that is the best way to do it. :)

Comment: I updated the awk program to exit upon seeing "Total Objects:" at the beginning of a line, and to check that there are at least 5 fields before checking the size.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is great at processing data rows with fields in it:

```sh
echo "$your_data" | awk '$3 < 3 {print $5}'
```

This code assumes that fields are always like this and never contain whitespace. It also assumes that all sizes in the third column are given as MiB.

(You might want to preprocess the data before giving it to awk to remove the trailing summary, or modify the awk script to dealk with the summary.)

EDIT: If the units alre also available in KiB you also have to check `$4`.  See [man awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) on how to do this.